# Spring Controller calling 2 times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

my spring controller is called 2 times from frontend URL. have checked all conf but no luck.
Spring version 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd

my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-    class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>  
        <!--    <param-value>classpath*:dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> -->        
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

in Application context -

```
<beans [...]>
    <bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false" />

        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="cnManager" />

    <bean class="com.myweb.lumin.spring.MvcConfiguringPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="converter"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.myweb.lumin.common.util.DozerConverter">
                    <property name="mapper">
                        <bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
                            <property name="mappingFiles">
                                <value>/WEB-INF/classes/dozer/dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

wrote simple controller - "hell0 worlds" controller calls 2 times..
am calling by URL (domain/serach), only problem in backend not in frontend
Not problem in frontend

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = Path.Url.SEARCH1, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(ModelMap modelMap, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request){   
    System.out.println("TEST 1");       
}
```

Comment: can you show the front end code?

Comment: how does your controller class looks like?

Comment: are you using Jquery in your front - end?, maybe the fron - end is calling twice.

Comment: not problem in frontend , trying to access only url..

Comment: What is `Path.Url.SEARCH1`?  Haven't seen that before.  Can you try with string like "/myTestPage"?  Also, have you written a unit test (for example, with Junit)?